# How to fix "runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'value_type' (stl_vector.h)" in leetcode?

Tags: c++

I am doing leetcode 376. Wiggle Subsequence.
It went wrong when testing the first instance of input [1,7,4,9,2,5]. It showed that "Line 922: Char 34: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'value_type' (stl_vector.h)". Could anyone tell me what is going wrong? Thanks a lot!

```
class Solution {
public:
    int wiggleMaxLength(vector<int>& nums) {
        if(nums.size() < 2){
            return nums.size();
        }
        std::priority_queue<int> big_heap;
        vector<int> flag;
        int result;
        int length = nums.size();
        for(int i = 0; i + 1 < length; i++){
            if(nums[i+1] > nums[i]){
            flag[i] = 1;
                }
            else if(nums[i+1] < nums[i]){
                flag[i] = -1;
            }
            else{
                flag[i] = 0;
            }
        }
        int count = 1;
        for(int i = 0; i + 2 < length;i++){
            cout <<flag[i]<<endl;
            if(flag[i] + flag[i+1] == 0){
                count ++;
            }
            else{
                big_heap.push(count);
                count = 1;
            }
        }
        big_heap.push(count);
        result = big_heap.top() + 1;
        return result;

    }
};
```

Comment: I suspect that this happens due to `vector<int> flag` not being initialized.
Move the declaration behind the line containing `int length = ...` and call `flag.resize(length);` after having declared flag.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Stack Overflow is a question-and-answer site for *specific questions* about actual code.  You need to learn to debug your code.  Questions of the form "This code doesn't work" are not on-topic on Stack Overflow and are likely to be downvoted.  See [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You have undefined behavior, because you are accessing elements of `flag` while it has size `0`.

If you want to write to `flag[i]` you first need to have an `i`th element in `flag`. You can achieve this by resizing `flag` to the length required, if you know it beforehand. In your case it seems like you will have exactly `length-1` elements, so you can do

```
flag.resize(length-1);
```

or if you move the declaration after the the one of `length`, you can directly use `std::vector`s constructor to do this:

```
std::vector<int> flag(length-1);
```

Alternatively you can use `push_back` to insert elements at the end of the vector, if you are simply writing sequentially new elements, as you seem to be doing here, e.g. instead of `flag[i] = 1;`:

```
flag.push_back(1);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! The problem has been solved.